# Why can't I attach my Player to a transform in my script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a script where the zombie looks for the player and if the player enters the boundaries it will start chasing it. My problem is that I can't attach my player to the script in the inspector and I am unsure why. I don't have a problem with the code(at least I don't think so) only with it not attaching. The player is a prefab from the unity Standard assets.

Edit: The script is attached to a prefab in my assets. The player in in the hierarchy.

Just in case here is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ZK_attack : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public Transform Player;
    public float MoveSpeed = 4.5f;
    public float MaxDist = 4.0f;
    public float MinDist = 1.5f;
    private Coroutine animat = null;
    private Animator anim;


    void Update()
    {
        

        transform.LookAt(Player);

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) >= MinDist)
        {
            transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool("inRadius", true);

            if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) <= MaxDist)
            {
                anim.SetBool("AttackingPlayer", true);


            }

        }

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) <= MinDist)
        {
            anim.SetBool("inRadius", false);
        }

        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) >= MaxDist)
        {
            anim.SetBool("AttackingPlayer", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that you can only drag objects into scripts that are in your scene already, unless they are prefabs themselves in the assests folder, even though it is on an object. To accomplish what you need, in your Start() add

```
Player = GameObject.Find("...name of object you wish to set as Player").transform;
```

Comment: Technically, you can drag things into prefabs. It's just that the only things you can drag into prefabs are other prefabs or other kinds of assets, not scene instances.